# Colorpicker changing 9 separate drawables?

Tags: android, colors, background, drawable, color-picker

I have 9 ImageViews that when onClick each open a colorpicker, I would like have the colorpicker change the color of a drawable correlating to that same view that was used the onclick at that time. I am unsure of how to conduct this? I have searched for examples online but cant seem to find anything that is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of colors that you want to select from, you can use a [level list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList). In XML, it might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/color_0"
        android:maxLevel="0" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/color_1"
        android:maxLevel="1" />
    . . .
</level-list>
```

You can then make this the drawable for an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and select which color to display by calling the image view's `setImageLevel()` method.

**EDIT**

You asked for an example of doing this programmatically. Let's say you have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="0"
            android:onClick="changeColor"
            android:text="Change color" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:tag="color_0" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="1"
            android:onClick="changeColor"
            android:text="Change color" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:tag="color_1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- etc. -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your activity, define your handler function something like this:

```
public void changeColor(View view) {
    String tag = "color_" + view.getTag();
    View target = findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewWithTag(tag);
    int color = getColorFromUser();
    target.setBackgroundColor(color); // or whatever you want to do
}
```

One might want to include some checking in this process for null tags, unfound views, the user canceling the color choice, etc.

Comment: this is great thank you, i will keep this in mind if all else fails, but i would really like to have the color picker for maximum amount of color choices

Comment: @user1148316 You just want a view that displays a solid color picked by the user? (Or, rather, 9 such views?)

Comment: i want 9 views to idepedantly open a colorwheel (i have working) and which ever view opened the wheel, to change the background color for a drawable directly related to that same view.

Comment: i can think of a way by having a seperate color wheel per each 9 views... but to spare having so many lines of code im sure there is a way to do it with one wheel

Comment: @user1148316 - If you're opening up the colorwheel in response to a click, you can capture the view and use it to select which drawable to update. You might also consider using view tags to hold the information you need to correlate to the drawable. You can retrieve the view tag in your onClick listener.

Comment: thank you for the replies, I am still pretty new to developing and not sure I understand how to accomplish what you are suggesting, would I be to much of a bother if I ask for an example?

Comment: thank you for your help Ted Hopp, i really appreciate it! i have a much better understanding of how i need to accomplish my goal now